# Is Doctrine persist() safe from SQL injection?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am wondering if the function `persist()` from Doctrine is safe to prevent SQL injection. I have searched, but after reading for a while, it still isn't clear to me. I am using Symfony 2:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($log);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: I would be extremely worried if one of the most popular ORM libraries in PHP was not protecting against SQL injection. Always good to know though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find answer to your question in Doctrine 2 documentation - [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/security.html#user-input-and-doctrine-orm)

> You can consider the following APIs to be safe from SQL injection ... All values on Objects inserted and updated through `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager#persist()`

So yes, `persist` should be safe from SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: Well, you could have mentioned that Doctrine is wrapped around `PDO` and uses prepared statements which is **what** makes Doctrine safe from injections. Anyway, there are places where you could potentially be opened to injections (i.e. if your write a DQL which includes a php variable such as `SELECT My\Entity u WHERE u.name = $username`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ORM will generate the SQL and pramaterize the query for you automatically.